# How do I parse ISO 8601 duration strings using Chrono?

Tags: rust, duration, rust-chrono

While `chrono` supports parsing of date, time and time zone in ISO 8601 compliant format, I am unable to find any method in the crate to parse duration strings such as `PT2M` which represents 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrono doesn't have any function to do this job.

Instead, use the [parse_duration](https://crates.io/crates/parse_duration) crate to solve the problem:

```rust
extern crate parse_duration;
use parse_duration::parse;

fn main() {
    print!("{:?}", parse("2 minutes"));
}
```

```
Ok(120s)
```

Furthermore, there isn't any function that converts ISO 8601 shortcuts into a representation for the chrono or parse_duration crate.

You need to write a parser that transforms the shortcuts like `PT2M` into a human readable form like `2 minutes`, if you work with the parse_duration crate.

If you want to use the chrono crate directly, you have a lot of calculation to do to put the duration into a numeric representation. I would take a look into the sources of `parse` in parse_duration.

---

One workaround could be to calculate the duration out of two `NaiveDate`s:

```rust
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::{Duration, NaiveDate};

fn main() {
    let d = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 8, 2);
    let tm1 = d.and_hms(0, 0, 0);
    let tm2 = d.and_hms(0, 2, 0);
    let delta: Duration = tm2.signed_duration_since(tm1);
    print!("{:?}", delta);
}
```

```
Duration { secs: 120, nanos: 0 }
```

Comment: I'm surprised at this result. I wouldn't have thought that `".:++++]][][[][[2]][minutes][]:}}}}"` was a valid duration.

Comment: I guess the OP knows how [ISO 8601](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm) works. Why would he ask otherwise explicit for a function to parse this format?

Comment: @Kaplan thanks for reference. Unfortunately, package has no longer updating notice. The reason I referenced chrono is that it is nearly feature complete with parsing ISO8601 duration. I would have very much liked to limit my dependencies.

Comment: I added a workaround that reduces the time-calculations, that are needed to instantiate a `Duration` directly. Nevertheless You must still write a parser which transforms the ISO 8601 eg. `PTM2` into `(0, 2, 0)` for 2 minutes.

Comment: @Shepmaster The workaround is an addendum in response to the OP's [latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121278717?noredirect=1) *limit my dependencies* and not a new solution.

Comment: @Kaplan sure... but why are you telling me this?

Comment: @Shepmaster Due to a *don't reply twice* comment, which has disappeared in the meantime. Sorry, I thought it came from you.

Answer (score 2):

Chrono doesn't have any function to do this job.

You can use [iso8601-duration](https://lib.rs/crates/iso8601-duration) crate instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [the `iso8601` crate](https://crates.io/crates/iso8601) which can parse durations and dates in that format.